# Getting relevant datasets of false negatives, false positives, true positive and true negative from confusion matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, confusion-matrix

I ran a random classifier on my text data and calculated a confusion matrix using the following code

```
#Plot the confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, normalize=False,figsize=(15,8))
```

[image]

The above fig is what my confusion matrix looks like. Now, I want to see some datasets that belong to false negatives, false positives, true positives and true negative?. So far written following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame(x_test)
df_test['case'] = np.where((y_test == 1) & (y_pred == 0), 'false negative', np.where((y_test == 0) & (y_pred == 1), 'false positive', 'correct prediction'))
df_test.head(5)
```

This code gives me false negative, false positive and correct predictions but does not give me true positive and true negative. Any idea how to modify this code so that `df_test` shows all these label results datasets:  false negative, false positive, true positive, true negative and correct predictions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a label array, then use numpy indexing index:

```
labels = np.array(['true negative',   # y_test, y_pred = 0,0
                   'false positive',  # y_test, y_pred = 0,1
                   'false negative',  # y_test, y_pred = 1,0
                   'true positive'    # y_test, y_pred = 1,1
                  ])

df_test['case'] = labesl[y_test * 2 + y_pred]
```

Comment: What about correct prediction ?

Comment: `df_test['correct'] = (y_test == y_pred)`?

Comment: Cant this be added inside of labels?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. correct prediction = true negative + true positive. How do you want the label look like?

Comment: True positive means correct prediction, right ?

Comment: Usually correct prediction means you prediction agrees with label (`y_pred==y_true`), whereas true positive means `y_pred==1 & y_true==1`

Comment: but are they are not same ? if y_pred=1 and y_pred=1 then y_pred==y_true ?